# For what value of $a\ f(x) = e^x + ax^3$ has inflection points

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I took the second derivative: $f^{''}(x)= e^x + 6ax$.

So $f$ has inflection points $\iff$ there exists $x_0$ such that $e^{x_0} + 6ax_0 = 0$.

I don't know how to go further and find such $a$ for which exists at least one positive root of that equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick $x_0$ in the domain of $f$, and then let $\displaystyle a = -\frac{e^{x_0}}{6x_0}$.

Checking that $f$ changes concavity at $x_0$, we now have $x_0$ as an inflection point of $f$.

Comment: By checking you mean pick one point on right of $x_0$ and one on the left and then evaluate function at these points? If $f$ has different signs, then $x_0$ satisfies our condition, right?

Comment: Evaluate $f''$. Since we're claiming this is the only inflection point, you only have to check the sign of $f''$ at arbitrary points to the left and right of $x_0$, yes. Otherwise, you'd have to check between $x_0$ and the other inflection points.

Comment: Picture $f(x) = x^4$. Then $f''(x) = 12x^2 $ has a $0$ at $0$, but $0$ is not an inflection point because the sign (hence, the concavity) doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Find the $\min_{x}\left\{\frac{\exp(x)}{x}\right\}$ which is $e$. Hence, $\forall ~m>e$ and $m<0, e^x-mx=0$ will have atleast one root.

Answer (score 0):

The solution $x_0$ of equation $$f^{''}(x)= e^x + 6ax=0$$ is explicitely given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $$x_0=-W\left(\frac{1}{6 a}\right)$$ and, in the real domain, it does exist if $$\frac{1}{6 a} \geq -\frac 1e$$ and $x_0>0$ for any $a<0$.